# My site is https, now i want to include iframe that are http, so how can i make a page only http from https.

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http, https

My website is https secured.
I want to make only a page unsecure like
www.mysite.com/fafoo

```
Background: My site is wordpress and i am using bellow codes in htaccess
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**My Target is to use unsecure website in iframe**

Answer (score 0):

- You can't include an http iframe in an https webpage

"But what if the iframe is https then redirect to http?"

- In an https webpage, an iframe that redirect to https will be blocked too.

It's a security mechanism (block active mixed content): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content